# json.dump segmentation fault: 11 with specific dictionnary data

Tags: python, json, segmentation-fault, dump

I am trying to save some dictionnary in python via json.dump. It works for all my data sets, except one which causes a segmentation fault: 11.

Here is the call to the routine:

`json.dump(mydatadict, outfile, allow_nan=True, sort_keys = True, indent = 4, ensure_ascii = False)`

Are there forbidden characters in json (like "\") and if so, how to remove them from strings ?

I can provide as attachement the dict data

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Actually, I found out that the segmentation fault was due to wrong encoding/delimiter specifications from me. Apparently, if you do not set the encoding format and delimiter properly, it can cause segmentation faults.

Comment: Actually, I have the same problem from the following dataset: I try to download this file: https://www.data.gouv.fr/s/resources/liste-des-marches-du-cias-de-la-communaute-dagglomeration-bar-le-duc-sud-meuse-2016/20170421-180850/Liste_marches_CIAS_2016_fournitures.csv into a dataframe, and it generates a segmentation fault which I do not understand. Here is the syntax: mydataframe = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=';', encoding='latin-1, engine='c'). Reading the data with utf-8 failed. The file can be opened on latin-3 from libre office but it is not supported by python

Comment: ` mydataframe = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=';', encoding='latin-1, engine='c')` -> missing `'` after latin-1 -> `SyntaxError`.  If you want to use `latin-3` use `iso-8859-3`.